# Yii form with one upload field

Tags: yii

I have a form with only one field in it.

```
<?php echo $form->fileFieldRow($model,'img',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
```

in my model I have setup that img is required

```
array('img', 'required'),
```

and I have added some file validation rules

```
array('img', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png' , 'maxFiles'=>'1'),
```

After selecting an image and pressing submit. I get the error that **'img' is required**. 
This is because the img is not set in the *Post* but in *Files*. So it doesn't see that img is set.

Is there a nice way to allow only one image upload field in a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your form

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'imageGallery-form',
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/Controller/action'),
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),// This is required for file upload
    )); ?>

<div class="row">
        <span class="span-4">Uplaod images:</span>
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'Img',array('id'=>'file')); ?>
     ?>
</div>
```

Add Some Script to validate the file field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#imageGallery-form').live("submit", function(event){
    var success = true;
    $form = $(this);
     if(/.*\.(gif)|(jpeg)|(jpg)|(doc)$/.test($("#file").val().toLowerCase())){
         $("#fname").removeClass("error");
    }else{
        $("#error_ul").append("<li>Please Choose Gif or Jpg Images Only.!!</li>");
        $(".errorSummary").show();
        $("#fname").addClass("error");
        success = false;
    }

}); 
</script>
```

And in Controller side access the image as shown

```
public function actionGetImage(){
    if(isset($_POST['imageUploadBtn'])){
        $Img=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'Img');
    }
```

}

Comment: For some reason the jquery **.live("submit")** does not seem to get triggered. The form also does not submit because it validates as img not set. But it does remove the error message. If I put the _action_  in the form, the form submits in a rather strange way. First it quickly shows the error message and then goes to the _create action_. I normally don't set an action meaning it just goes to the current controller. I could remove the *img* as required but then the form submits without even having selecting an image at all.

Comment: Comment these two lines and check 
array('img', 'required'),
array('img', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png' , 'maxFiles'=>'1'),

Comment: I removed the validation now. Is there a alternative way to trigger the jquery *live* function because now it submits without any validation. Thanks alot.

Comment: Did u add the script provided in my post it should validate it before submit

Comment: Yes, as follows: `$(function() {    
       $('#imageGallery-form').live("submit", function(event){
           ...
       }); 
}); ` If I change the *live* to a *bind* it does seem to work. But not sure this the correct way

Comment: It should work coz it works fine for me check it once again there might be some syntax errors .Or try using simple test form with submit button and the above script function using alerts to check if it works

Comment: This is the error I get from the js 
`Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 77`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31803/discussion-between-ninad-and-minahalmon)

Comment: Can u post your view file ill check it

Comment: I have solved it mostly I think. Not sure what *live* does but I changed it to:  `$('#imageGallery-form').submit(function() {`
_http://api.jquery.com/submit/_
It then submitted the form twice. After removing the _clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),_ this was solved